# Wrong groovy is loaded when using groovy from my intelliJ idea plugin

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I am developing an intelliJ plugin using groovy as development language.

My system has groovy 2.1.7 as default, but intelliJ idea uses groovy 2.0.6 (in `lib/`).

When I start idea with my plugin, I got this exception on loading my Groovy class.

```
Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.1.7 and you are trying to load version 2.0.6
```

Here is top backtrace.

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.1.7 and you are trying to load version 2.0.6
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:509)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:71)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:192)
    at io.github.tomykaira.accelvoice.ideaplugin.NextInsertionHolder.$getStaticMetaClass(NextInsertionHolder.groovy)
    at io.github.tomykaira.accelvoice.ideaplugin.NextInsertionHolder.<init>(NextInsertionHolder.groovy)
    at io.github.tomykaira.accelvoice.ideaplugin.AccelVoiceModule.moduleAdded(AccelVoiceModule.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleImpl.moduleAdded(ModuleImpl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleManagerImpl$4.run(ModuleManagerImpl.java:535)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1013)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleManagerImpl.fireModuleAddedInWriteAction(ModuleManagerImpl.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleManagerComponent$3$1.run(ModuleManagerComponent.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:343)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Please check your IntelliJ settings under:

Project Structure/Global Libraries - remove 2.0.6 version

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have anything listed under Project Structure/Global Libraries or Project Structure/Libraries, so the two answers above unfortunately didn't work for me.

What did work was this:  I located the `groovy-all` directory, which for me was in

```
/Users/<username>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all
```

This directory contained both the versions it mentioned in the error message in IntelliJ.  I renamed the one that it was saying it was already using (2.4.10, in my case), which allowed it to use the one it said it was trying to load (2.4.12, which I wanted).

This worked, but upon re-syncing with gradle, it downloaded 2.4.10 again into that folder.  Happily though, IntelliJ now seems to be ignoring it, and I no longer see the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I checked my IntelliJ settings under:

Project Structure/Global Libraries

and there I saw nothing.

Then I looked in Project Structure/Libraries and there I found a module that was two different groovvy-all versions (2.4.1 and 2.4.5).

Once I deleted the incorrect groovy version, the issue got resolved.